# How to play an audio file in my server on facebook? is it possible?

Tags: facebook, audio

I need to play a shared audio link on facebook, like youtube videos. the audio file is in my server. is it possible?

Please help me to resolve this issue!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Open Graph meta tags to achieve it. All you have to do is adding the required Open Graph meta tags to the URL that is being shared.

This is a short example I took from the [Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/property-types/#audio):

```
<meta property="og:audio"              content="http://my-audio.mp3">
<meta property="og:audio:secure_url"   content="https://my-audio.mp3">
<meta property="og:audio:type"         content="audio/mp3">
```